# Windows service installer not reading App.Config file

Tags: c#, windows-services, installation, app-config

I have added App.Config  in my project.
I have a installer class(ProjectInstaller.cs) which needs to read values from App.config.
I am providing the keys .
Below is the sample Code :

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CONFIG_FILE"]
```

I am getting null values as per above code ,when invoked in Installer class.
But in App.Config file the value for the above key exists.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/379276/windows-service-cant-access-app-config-from-within-my-installers-constructor for what's going on and the best fixes - you can't work with an app.config directly from an installer as your application isn't actually running yet. Rather, it's `installutil` that's running. Note, by the way, that as you're writing a question this site will suggest possible answers -- read them!

Answer (score 22):

Try:

```
public string GetServiceNameAppConfig(string serviceName)
{
    var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(MyServiceInstaller)).Location);
    return config.AppSettings.Settings[serviceName].Value;
}
```

Comment: This solution works, and doesn't require setup project. Thanks.

Comment: By far the best solution.

Answer (score 3):

Google helps: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ar/winformssetup/thread/896e110e-692d-4934-b120-ecc99b01c562

the point is that your installer is **NOT** running as exe alone and an app.config called whatever you imagine will not be loaded by default as the exe running your installer is **InstallUtil.exe** and it would eventually search appSettings from the file **InstallUtil.exe.config** which is not yours and is not what you want, read the following and check the links...

> If you invoke it through InstallUtil then the configuration file is
>   defined as InstallUtil.exe.config which is not what you want.  You
>   could manually load the config file using Configuration but it will
>   probably be a little messy
>
> The trick is in the execution context of the installer classes. If you
>   install your app using InstallUtil all code will be executed in the
>   same process as InstallUtil.exe. If you need to pass some data to the
>   Installer class during deployment you should use install parameters.
>   They are passed to the installer during execution of Install, Commit,
>   Rollback and Uninstall methods by the execution enviroment
>   (installutil, windows instller...). You can access there parameters
>   using InstallContex property ot the installer class.
>
> There is a excellent artiicle on CodeProject regarding Setup projects
>   and parameters:
>   http://www.codeproject.com/dotnet/SetupAndDeployment.asp
>
> Check out
>   http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.install.installcontext.aspx

Comment: Thanks Davide, I have defined some important key values in my App.Config.I need to read them.Is there no way I could get it.Do I physically need to create a physical xml file.

Comment: as I wrote in my answer, please read this one: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/SetupAndDeployment.aspx

Answer (score 1):

For me the easiest solution was to create InstallUtil.exe.config file, and fill it up with content from application config file. Service installer successfully read from this config file.

I created my service by following steps described in: [Host a WCF Service in a Managed Windows Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Davide Piras explained very well, why you can't use your app.config and suggests to pass your values as parameters.

I found a nice and helpful article on how to pass parameters to the `installutil.exe` and use them in the `serviceInstaller` or `projectInstaller`:

Part 1: [Using Parameters with InstallUtil](http://diaryofadeveloper.wordpress.com/2012/05/26/configuring-windows-services-with-parameters-from-installutil/)

Part 2: [Configuring Windows Services with Parameters from InstallUtil](http://diaryofadeveloper.wordpress.com/2012/05/26/configuring-windows-services-with-parameters-from-installutil/)

It explains very shortly how to pass arguments and how to read them.