# Set windows service account in config

Tags: c#, configuration, windows-services, service-accounts, service-installer

I need to set the serviceaccount for a windows service in the config file. But I cannot access the config values in the installer. I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7633918/windows-service-installer-not-reading-app-config-file) question but I do not want to use install parameters. Is there any way to do this?

**EDIT:**
And I also tried [some solutions in this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379276/windows-service-cant-access-app-config-from-within-my-installers-constructor) but I can't access Configuration or ConfigurationManager inside the installer class... Am I supposed to add some reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research, I found my own solution...

First add a reference to System.Configuration

and then add the following code in the installer class

```
Assembly service = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(ProjectInstaller));
string assemblyPath = service.Location;
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(assemblyPath);
KeyValueConfigurationCollection mySettings = config.AppSettings.Settings;
processInstaller.Account = (ServiceAccount)Enum.Parse(typeof(ServiceAccount), mySettings["Account"].Value);
```

I am just so happy right now!! :)